# How to condition the loop for one column to fill another column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the dataframe

[image]

I need is
if **Beat** column value is Nan , it should be filled as 0 in the **Disease** column

if **Beat** column value is anything except Nan , it should be filled as 1 in the **Disease** column

What i have tried so far ,

```
if a['Beat'].value('NaN'):
    a['Disease'].fillna(0)
else:
    a['Disease'].fillna(1)
```

Also tried this

```
if a['Beat']=='NaN':
    a['Disease'].fillna(0)
else:
    a['Disease'].fillna(1)
```

Both of them didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need `1` if not missing value else `0`, so possible solutions are test not missing values by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and convert it to `0, 1`:

```
#if possible `NaN` is string convert to missing values
a = a.replace('NaN', np.nan)
```

---

```
a['Disease'] = a['Beat'].notna().astype(int)

a['Disease'] = a['Beat'].notna().view('i1')

a['Disease'] = np.where(a['Beat'].notna(), 1, 0)

a['Disease'] = np.where(a['Beat'].isna(), 0, 1)
```

**Sample**:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Beat': [np.nan, 5, np.nan]})

#e.g. this solution, all working same
a['Disease'] = np.where(a['Beat'].isna(), 0, 1)
print (a)
   Beat  Disease
0   NaN        0
1   5.0        1
2   NaN        0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `loc`:

```
a['Disease'] = a['Disease'].fillna(0)
a.loc[a['Beat'].isna(), 'Disease'] = 1
```

Or try `fillna`:

```
a['Disease'] = a['Disease'].fillna(a['Beat'].notna().astype(int))
```